# Total inductance of two Parallel aiding inductors each with an inductor in series

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, inductance

what would be the total inductance of this circuit? 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZHEB.png]

Comment: 'Parallel aiding inductors' = transformer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Chu, \$L_1\$ and \$L_4\$ are coupled in your schematics. With defining the coupling as \$M = M_{34}\$, the resulting inductance becomes

\$L = \frac{(L_1+L_2) (L_3+L_4) - M^2}{(L_1+L_2+L_3+L_4) - 2 M}\$

In case they are not coupled (not forming a transformer) we set \$M = 0\$ and get the equation from Joe Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Inductors add just like resistors. So combine the inductors in series to get just 2 inductors in parallel. Then add those two parallel inductors by adding together their reciprocals.

Edit: Then take the reciprocal of that answer. I forgot about this last part. Very important.

\$\frac{(L_{1}+L_{2})(L_{3}+L{4})}{L_{1}+L_{2}+L_{3}+L_{4}}\$

Formula for calculating inductors in parallel is the following:

\$ \frac{1}{L_{total}} = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N}\,\frac{1}{L_{n}} = \frac{1}{L_{1}}+\frac{1}{L_{2}}\,...+\frac{1}{L_{N}}\$

Formula for calculating inductors in series:

\$ L_{total} = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N}{L_{n}} = L_{1}+L_{2}\,...+ \,{L_{N}}\$

Comment: Your equation should be1/ /(L1+L2)+/(L3+L4). You are taking the reciprocal of the reciprocals. Do you know Mathjax or LaTex or any markup language?

Comment: You’re right. I forgot about the last reciprocal.

Comment: L1 and L4 form a transformer.